# Getting Error: List id must be an object after adding schema to todos example in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

The todos example for Meteor works fine. However, when I added a schema to the Todos and Lists collections I keep getting "Error: List id must be an object". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Added were:
    meteor add aldeed:simple-schema
    meteor add aldeed:collection2

Here is the new schema added to the collections.js file:

```
Lists = new Mongo.Collection('lists');

var Schema = {};

Schema.Lists = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  incompleteCount: {
    type: Number
  }
});

Lists.attachSchema(Schema.Lists);

Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');

Schema.Todos = new SimpleSchema({
  listId: {
    type: Object
  },
  text: {
    type: String
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date
  }
});

Todos.attachSchema(Schema.Todos);
```

---

Nothing else changed.

Before I started meteor, I did a "meteor reset".

Here is the error from the bootstrap.js file when attempting to attach the _id (list_id) of the new list to the listId object from the Todos schema:
            .
            .
            .
    {name: "Favorite Scientists",
       items: ["Ada Lovelace",
               "Grace Hopper",
               "Marie Curie",
               "Carl Friedrich Gauss",
               "Nikola Tesla",
               "Claude Shannon"
              ]
           }
         ];

```
     var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
     _.each(data, function(list) {
       var list_id = Lists.insert({name: list.name,
         incompleteCount: list.items.length});

       _.each(list.items, function(text) {     //line 43
         Todos.insert({listId: list_id,        //line 44
                       text: text,
                       createdAt: new Date(timestamp)});
         timestamp += 1; // ensure unique timestamp.
       });
     });
```

---

```
(STDERR)                        throw(ex);
(STDERR)                              ^
(STDERR) Error: List id must be an object
(STDERR)     at getErrorObject (meteor://ðŸ’»app/packages/aldeed_collection2-core/lib/collection2.js:345:1)
(STDERR)     at [object Object].doValidate (meteor://ðŸ’»app/packages/aldeed_collection2-core/lib/collection2.js:328:1)
(STDERR)     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as insert] (meteor://ðŸ’»app/packages/aldeed_collection2-core/lib/collection2.js:83:1)
(STDERR)     at meteor://ðŸ’»app/server/bootstrap.js:44:1
(STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
(STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (meteor://ðŸ’»app/packages/underscore/underscore.js:105:1)
(STDERR)     at meteor://ðŸ’»app/server/bootstrap.js:43:1
(STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
(STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (meteor://ðŸ’»app/packages/underscore/underscore.js:105:1)
(STDERR)     at meteor://ðŸ’»app/server/bootstrap.js:39:1
```

=> Meteor server restarted
=> Started your app.

Answer (score 0):

`Lists.insert()` returns the _id of the newly created object, which is a string, so your list_id variable is returning a string and invalidating your schema.  Change your Schema.Todos listId type to String instead of Object.

```
Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');

Schema.Todos = new SimpleSchema({
  listId: {
    type: String
  },
  text: {
    type: String
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that was it! I appreciate the help and your quick reply.